# django-rest-framework get the timestamp since the object created through serialization

Tags: django, datetime, serialization, django-rest-framework, timestamp

I need to get the time since a post object was created. While surfing the internet I have found the following implementation and it gives me the following error

Adding `@property` to  models post object

```
class Post(models.Model):

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def timesince(self):
        return timesince.timesince(self.timestamp)
```

The `PostSerializer`

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timesince = serializers.DateTimeField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields('__all__')
```

I get the following `AttributeError`

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `timesince` on serializer `PostSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you define the fields is wrong; the correct syntax is

```py
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
```